# Propper java-groovy interoperability: how?

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, grooid

I managed to integrate `grooid` into my plain android project, so it could compile, with all those lint, multidex magic (yes, I fixed 65k limit problem), and successfully run on a device

Then I created a `src/main/groovy` folder, moved one of my java activities into it and turned it to a groovy class:

```
package com.mypackage

@CompileStatic
class SplashActivity extends Activity {

  void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate savedInstanceState
    contentView = R.layout.splash
  }
}
```

upon compiling, I get a compile errors like:

> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> AuthHelper.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
>
> import com.mypackage.SplashActivity;
>
> ```
>               ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class SplashActivity

So, the groovy files must be somehow compiled before `compile*JavaWithJavac`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you place the java files into the groovy folder the groovy compiler will facilitate joint compilation.

You can also use the skipJavaC flag to get joint compilation as well see https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin#only-use-groovyc for more information.